# Display inline throwing an error

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a textbox which is hidden using display = none. I am trying to change it to visible on some condition, however it does not seem to work. I have checked that the control is going to the change event. I have tried various ways to get it to work, the 3 ways that I have tried are within the $('body')

```
colValue = "<input id ='val' class='value' value ='" + field.Value + "'style = 'display: none'/>";
```

I have tried these different things to get it to show the control. None of these work.

```
    $('#val').css("display", "block");
    $('#val').css('display', 'inline');
    $('#val').css({ "display": "inline" });
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: You don't have quotes around your selectors. Should be `$("#val")`. Not posting as an answer because I don't think simple syntax errors warrant one - voted to close.

Comment: Voting to Close as this question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

Comment: That was my mistake due to a copy paste, where I wanted to simplify the code than paste the existing complicated code. And I am still not able to get it to work.

Comment: @The_Outsider You still have not put quotes around `inline` in the third line, which is also necessary. `$('#val').css({ display: "inline" });` - Granted, this line is no different than your second line. You can just leave your second line as-is and delete this line altogether.

Answer (score 2):

*Edit*
So your issue appears to be that the box isn't appearing after a change event. Ensure that your HTML IDs are unique, and that your change handler is getting wired up after the DOM is ready. If those are all true the issue likely exists outside of the code fragment you've shown, since the code you've provided should work. One thing to note is that the `change` event doesn't get fired until the control being changed loses focus. If it's another textbox, you have to click out of the box before the event gets fired. See the example below (note: I'm using [`show`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) to update the element's visibility since that's more idiomatic, but it should be functionally equivalent to what you attempted.)

```js
$(function() {
    $('body').on('change', '.condition', function () {    
        $('#val').show();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Text Box 1 <input id ='val' class='value' value='test' style='display: none' type='text'/> <br />
Text Box 2 <input class='condition' type='text'/>
```

---

There's no variable named `inline` in your application. Wrap it in quotes and make it a string. Additionally, you're trying to change the style, so you have to call the appropriate method (See docs for [`css`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) method):

```
$("#val").css("display", "inline");
```

Comment: I have corrected myself. The three lines inside the body are 3 ways i am trying to set it right. None of the 3 seem to work. Isn't your solution similar to the second line in my code?

Comment: @The_Outsider What error are you trying to solve? My answer explains and addresses the `ReferenceError` you mentioned in your post. That's the only error you've mentioned, other than "it does not seem to work". If you have a larger issue, update your question, and I can try to address it.

Comment: Hopefully the new edit will give you a clearer picture of my issue.

Comment: @The_Outsider Updated.